# Get array in Python from Swift via ctypes

Tags: python, arrays, swift, return, ctypes

I am trying to call a swift function which returns a float array in python. I am using ctypes to load the compiled swift library and to define the type of the native function. The result I get in Python from the native function differs from the values that I hardcoded in Swift. Can somebody help me figuring out, what I am doing wrong?

---

**`mySwiftLib.swift`**

```swift
import Foundation

@_cdecl("get_float_array")
public func getFloatArray() -> [CFloat] {
    return [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
}
```

compiled with `swiftc -emit-library -o ./libMySwiftLib mySwiftLib.swift`

---

**`main.py`**

```python
import ctypes

swift_lib = ctypes.CDLL('./libMySwiftLib')

# define arguments and result type 
result_array_length = 4 # swift array length
swift_lib.get_float_array.argtypes = []
swift_lib.get_float_array.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float * result_array_length)

# call swift lib function
result = swift_lib.get_float_array()
print("result from native call: ", result)

# get actual array from result pointer
arr = [i for i in result.contents]
print("result array: ", arr)

# XXX:
# actual: [2.285883241727672e-30, 1.401298464324817e-45, 2.802596928649634e-45, 0.0]
# expected: [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
```

run with `python3 main.swift`

Comment: maybe my approach with list comprehension (`arr = [i for i in result.contents]`) is totally wrong and there is another way of dereferencing the pointer in `result`?

Answer (score 0):

From my testing, you can give or receive swift array to/from python.
You need to use UnsafePointer or UnsafeBufferPointer like this:

```
@_cdecl("add")
public func add(a: UnsafePointer<Double>, size: Int) -> Double {
    let buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: a, count: size)
    return buffer.reduce(.zero, +)
}

// cannot be marked @_cdecl
public func adder(a: UnsafeBufferPointer<Double>, size: Int) -> Double {
    return a.reduce(.zero, +)
}

@_cdecl("get_double_array")
public func getDoubleArray() -> UnsafePointer<Double> {
    return UnsafePointer<Double>([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])
}

public func getDoubleArray2() -> UnsafeBufferPointer<Double> {
    let a = UnsafePointer<Double>([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])
    return UnsafeBufferPointer(start: a, count: 4)
}
```

UnsafeBufferPointer cannot be represented in objective-c and thus cannot be used with @_cdecl. Therefore, you need to take care of the name mangling of the function in the library.

Hope this helps
Vincent